# How can I run old games on Windows 7 with a DirectX 9 error?

Tags: windows-7, backwards-compatibility, directx-9, command-and-conquer-3-tiberium-wars, command-and-conquer-red-alert-3

I have installed Command & Conquer Tiberium Wars on my Windows 7 laptop and updates. However, when I try to run it I see this error<sup>1</sup>:

[image: Direct X error]

To answer the points in the dialog:

- I have DirectX 11 installed
- The video card (and laptop) are pretty new
- I can't verify hardware acceleration; the option is greyed out (and the graphics card own menu does not appear to have this option)

I've already tried Googling this and found lots of pages of people reporting the same error but have not found a working solution. I've also tried running it with various compatibility versions and screen resolutions.

I have also tried:

- installing standalone DirectX 9
- disabling user account control (see [comment below](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/258712/how-can-i-run-old-games-on-windows-7-with-a-directx-9-error#comment360466_258712))
  My 64 bit Windows 7 version has service pack 1 installed.

I have also tried this on a different laptop (but with Windows 7) and got the same result.

I also saw exactly the same error with Command & Conquer Red Alert 3.

<sub>1 Adding text to make this more "Googleable": *"**DirectX Error** Please make sure you have DirectX 9.0 or higher installed. Also verify that your video card meets the minimum requirements, and that you do not have hardware acceleration disabled in the Display control panel."*</sub>

Comment: The Steam store page for this game has this notice on it: "WINDOWS 7 USERS: To ensure proper functionality, you must disable User Account Control ("UAC") via the Windows Control Panel before launching the game." Have you tried that?

Comment: @RossRidge thanks for the tip. I did not try that when I posted the question but just did after reading your comment. No change - same error message (for this and other games).

Comment: I have command and conquer the first decade on my 64-bit windows 7 and the only problems I have is lagging problems in Yuri's Revenge and Command and Conquer 1 and Red Alert 1 have strange graphics errors such as pink pixels. I don't know what mine is but could the problem be with the Video Card. otherwise try setting compatibility mode to something like XP or 95 and fiddle with the other options

Comment: @Memor-X - I've tried every compatibility mode; nothing seems to work.

Comment: You can have DX9 and DX11 installed on the same system I fact it's required to run DX9 games

Comment: @Ramhound: indeed, I installed standalone DX9 but still get the same error.

Comment: I know C&C Generals has this issue, and there, a library that was left behind in the game folder from its testing days was the culprit, namely "dbghelp.dll", and deleting it fixes the issue. But I have no idea if the same thing applies to C&C3.